# Can't figure out how to encode string into URL for Google Static Map API iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

I'm literally desperate right now. I've been coding and debugging for 7 hours straight, from figuring out how to draw a circle into a Google Static Map, converting codes from PHP and Java to Swift just to see if solutions would work.

Fortunately I was lucky enough and I was able to generate a Google Static Map with Circle properly. HOWEVER, my problem now is how to encode it (String URL) properly into URL. I have tried almost everything I found on SO.

Here's a sample working URL in my browser from my logs:

[WORKING GOOGLE STATIC MAP LINK](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x320&&path=color:0x2EB7FCDD%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor:0x2EB7FC80%7Cenc:umdxAip_bVFqARmA%5EiAl@aAt@w@%60Ao@dAa@jASlAGlAFjARdA%60@%60An@t@v@l@%60A%5EhARlAFpAGnASlA_@hAm@%60Au@x@aAl@eA%60@kARmAFmAGkASeAa@aAm@u@y@m@aA_@iASmA&key=AIzaSyDLDkhgnS5gUjlXl5Jqt8fxJq87Figz8co&zoom=15)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x320&&path=color:0x2EB7FCDD%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor:0x2EB7FC80%7Cenc:umdxAip_bVFqARmA^iAl@aAt@w@`Ao@dAa@jASlAGlAFjARdA`@`An@t@v@l@`A^hARlAFpAGnASlA_@hAm@`Au@x@aAl@eA`@kARmAFmAGkASeAa@aAm@u@y@m@aA_@iASmA&key=AIzaSyDLDkhgnS5gUjlXl5Jqt8fxJq87Figz8co&zoom=15
```

And I have tried every `CharacterSet` for encoding that string into URL.

Some of the results are:

```
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- HOST --> https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fstaticmap%3Fsize=640x320&&path=color%3A0x2EB7FCDD%257Cweight%3A1%257Cfi ... &zoom=15
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- QUERY --> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x320&&path=color:0x2EB7FCDD%257Cweight:1%257Cfillcolor:0x2EB7FC80%257Cenc:umdxAip_bVFqARmA%5EiAl@aAt@w@%60Ao@dAa@jASlAGlAFjARdA%60@%60An@t@v@l@%60A%5EhARlAFpAGnASlA_@hAm@%60Au@x@aAl@eA%60@kARmAFmAGkASeAa@aAm@u@y@m@aA_@iASmA&key=AIzaSyDLDkhgnS5gUjlXl5Jqt8fxJq87Figz8co&zoom=15
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- WHITE SPACES --> %68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%6D%61%70%73%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%61%70%69%73%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%6D%61%70%73%2F%61%70%69%2F%73%74%61 ... 3D%31%35
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- nonBaseCharacters --> %68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%6D%61%70%73%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%61%70%69%73%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%6D%61%70%73%2F%61%70%69%2F%73%74%61 ... 3D%31%35
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- alphanumerics --> https%3A%2F%2Fmaps%2Egoogleapis%2Ecom%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fstaticmap%3Fsize%3D640x320%26%26path%3Dcolor%3A0x2EB7FCDD%257Cweigh ... oom%3D15
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- urlFragmentAllowed --> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x320&&path=color:0x2EB7FCDD%257Cweight:1%257Cfillcolor:0x2EB7FC80%257Cenc:umdxAip_bVFqARmA%5EiAl@aAt@w@%60Ao@dAa@jASlAGlAFjARdA%60@%60An@t@v@l@%60A%5EhARlAFpAGnASlA_@hAm@%60Au@x@aAl@eA%60@kARmAFmAGkASeAa@aAm@u@y@m@aA_@iASmA&key=AIzaSyDLDkhgnS5gUjlXl5Jqt8fxJq87Figz8co&zoom=15
GPKit -- JobLocationTableViewCell 2017-08-04 19:55:53 +0000: -- decomposables --> %68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%6D%61%70%73%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%61%70%69%73%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%6D%61%70%73%2F%61%70%69%2F%73%74%61 ... 3D%31%35
```

None of these work neither in my browser or in my image downloader function. Swift or Objective-C answers are welcome.

EDIT: Of course I use the URL for downloading the generated static map image, like so (I'm using a library called `Kingfisher`)

```
let mapURL = URL(string: staticMapUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
self.imageView_Map.kf.setImage(
    with: mapURL,
    placeholder: nil,
    options: [.transition(.fade(1))],
    progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) in
    }, completionHandler: { (_, _, _, _) in })
```

Comment: Put in your code and what you are trying to do with the URL.

Comment: Although I feel like it's unnecessary, there you go.

Comment: What is the value of `mapURL` in this call?  When you are saying you tried every CharacterSet, what do you mean by that?

Comment: `mapURL` is supposedly a URL from the working string I posted above. I have tried every `CharacterSet` available for encoding the said string, just trying out my luck because it is my first time to encounter such a problem - a non-encodeable string into URL. That's why I need help.

Comment: You should show your code for creating mapURL. I have no idea why you would need to care about CharacterSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kingfisher docs say:

```
  let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
  imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

So, all you need to do is

```
  let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x320&&path=color:0x2EB7FCDD%7Cweight:1%7Cfillcolor:0x2EB7FC80%7Cenc:umdxAip_bVFqARmA%5EiAl@aAt@w@%60Ao@dAa@jASlAGlAFjARdA%60@%60An@t@v@l@%60A%5EhARlAFpAGnASlA_@hAm@%60Au@x@aAl@eA%60@kARmAFmAGkASeAa@aAm@u@y@m@aA_@iASmA&key=AIzaSyDLDkhgnS5gUjlXl5Jqt8fxJq87Figz8co&zoom=15")
  imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

I don't see what you need to encode.

Comment: I thought that every string url must be encoded to be converted into a URL, since I'm doing that everytime, and I've been trying the solution you posted before I posted this question. It's returning me a `nil`. 4:45AM here. I'm so disappointed with myself lol.

Comment: The URL you posted is already encoded.  If you needed to make that URL from parts you would need to encode each part

Comment: Indeed, because I used a library that used to encode lots of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to generate such a cute string URL. What's the real solution that you're saying now, sir?

Comment: I can't even say I understand your problem, so I don't have any more of a solution.  You need to show how you are creating mapURL if you want us to help you create it correctly

Comment: I just edited the question when you posted your last comment above, 13 minutes ago. I don't understand why do I need to show countless ways I have tried to make a loadable URL object. Like what I've said, I've also tried your solution before going here. Tried encoding and whatever. To make the question more straight to the point, I just need to know how to make the `WORKING GOOGLE STATIC MAP LINK` I generated be loadable into my `UIImageView`. Or maybe I'll just try ditching this `Kingfisher` just for this part of my project.

Comment: I'm selecting this an answer instead of posting my own solution, because the solution can be found in your comments. For the people like me in the future who will read this, figure out everything why converting a string into a URL generates an error or is nil. Read your URL String first, is it encoded already? Does it have the `%` signs? If it does, it is most likely encoded already, try online tools such as: http://www.url-encode-decode.com to see if your url string has some parts that is already encoded.